# How to fix weird Designer view errors?

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, package, android-support-library

Since I updated to target android Pie, I got this weird error in the designer view that seems to affect the support.v7 package.
After some time trying to figure it out by myself and googling the problem, I still cant fix it.

The builds work just fine but not having a designer to see changes in the UI is quite troublesome

Screenshots of the designer errors:

[image]

I have tried going back to Oreo versions and re-downloading all packages to see if it will fix the problem with no success.

```
<!--Removed TextView and similar component information to reduce lines-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:title="ITM"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"/>
    <!--Main View-->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            app:columnCount="2"
            app:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="20dp">
            <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
                app:columnCount="2"
                app:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
                <TextView/>
                <TextView/>
                <TextView/>
                <TextView/>
                <TextView/>
                <TextView/>
                <TextView/>
                <TextView/>
                <TextView/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
            <View/>
            <TextView/>
            <Switch/>
            <TextView/>
            <TextView />
            <Switch/>
            <TextView/>
            <TextView/>
            <Switch/>
            <TextView/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
<!--Only part that shows is here-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView/>
        <Button/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add the entire stack trace here

Comment: Not sure what a stack trace is

Comment: You have two screenshots showing it partially, copy paste the entire error message here.

Comment: Upon further researching, I found that it might be very possible its from the designer API selector- but the selector has only API 26 (not 28) and nothing else. And I have no idea how to add more

Comment: could you describe more specifically，what issue now? i run your code and it works well

Comment: Because its not the code - its something to do with the API version. When I have the designer for 26 when I chose the app to be for 28, I cannot change the designer's API to anything other than 26

Answer (score 0):

After I gave up on fixing it on Visual Studio 2017, I have found out that installing 2019 version fixes this issue completely.

Kind of sad that they force you to use latest version but it is the only viable option I can find